# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, windows, permissions

When trying to use "grunt build", I get the following warning

```
Warning: Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
directory .tmp/styles
        error app/styles/main.scss \
(C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chunky_png-1.4.0/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:43:in `initialize': \
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/some folders/.tmp/styles/ui/images/flags-sa787615a22.png)
    Compilation failed in 1 files.
    Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.
```

From what I can understand, it's trying to write an image but it can't because of permissions. I installed Ruby with admin rights and I'm using VS Code's terminal to execute "grunt build", which I also started up as administrator. When going to the properties of the folder SYSTEM, my account and administrators have full control.

I found similar problems, but almost all of the solutions were for Linux (I'm using Windows 11) and as they stated it was because of permission errors, I can't think of anything else than using admin rights.

Comment: What happens if you use the same terminal to `touch` that same path?

Comment: Since this happens when you write the file, it could mean that you don't have permissions on the file, or on the directory the file is in. Since you are on Windows, it could also be that some process is holding a lock on the file handle.  It would also be helpful if you would indicate which Ruby implementation you are using.

Comment: @JaredBeck this will succesfully create a file, I even tried to give its name a lot of characters so the path size isn't too large and it still works fine. Also giving the exact same name (flags-sa787615a22.png) will succesfully create a png file.

Comment: @user1934428 as both my account and administrators (I tried running VS Code as admin) have full control on the folder, I should have the right permissions I think. My Ruby version is: ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x64-mingw-ucrt]

Comment: I also have local admin rights on my Windows machine, and there are a few old files which I can't remove. That's why I would first try to fiddle with the file using Windows Explorer. If it doesn't work, you can at least rule out Ruby from the case.

Comment: @user1934428 I already tried creating files myself in that folder and that works, both using Windows Explorer and the VS Code terminal.

Comment: I find it strange that your application wants to **create** a picture file, while **compiling** scss. I would have a look at `png_encoding.rb`: What exactly is happening there, and where is the initializer being called from?

Comment: I just reinstalled everything and put the project directly in my C drive. It works now. So the problem likely lied with either my personal folder and/or ruby.